# Android Studio (Intellij) incomplete unicode support?

Tags: android, unicode, intellij-idea, android-studio

I get "boxes" displayed when I'm trying to input unicode characters in the Android Studio dialog boxes. However, I can type the same characters in the main editor.

Please, see the marked area on the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Android Studio no longer have this issue (at least 3+)